# In an open-circuited transmission line (microwave circuits) the current in the return path is completely zero?

Tags: transmission-line, microwave

Since the current meets the open boundary and gets reflected back does this mean that the return path has zero current always on it? Or there is also a standing wave there as well with a current with an opposite direction of propagation?

The same I would ask about a lambda/2 dipole antenna which is a standing wave line as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "return path"?

Comment: Are you asking what happens at the point of the open boundary condition? Or are you asking what happens along the whole length of the line leading to the boundary?

Comment: The return path I mean the second wire or metal plate. For a coaxial it would be the outer wire. For a waveguide of parallel plates would be the bottom plate.

Comment: @bigboss no, very much not.

Comment: @bobbs I don't get what you mean with no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transmission line doesn't have a "supply path" and a "return path". The two conductors that make up a TL are coupled throughout their length so that they always have opposite currents — this is what makes it a transmission line, and it's true even if you're "only driving one side", with the other referenced to ground.

The relationship between voltage and current in a transmission line changes along its length; if one end is an open circuit then there is zero current there, but a short distance away the current is nonzero (in a sense, the current at that point sees the remaining TL stub as a capacitor), and a quarter wavelength away the current reaches a maximum.

Comment: So... In my case in the second conductor we would have a standing wave across the conductor with opposite orientation?

Comment: @bigboss yes, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that, at the open end of the transmission line or antenna, the current is zero.  At other points on the line, there is a nonzero current; it's at a maximum 1/4 wavelength from the open end.  In your dipole, that's 1/4 wavelength from each end, putting it at the center feed point.  The voltage is maximum at the open end(s) and minimum at the feed point, but nonzero based on the characteristic impedance of the antenna.

Comment: What I ask is what happens on the second "wire" or "metal plate" of the transmission line in open circuit conditions. The current cannot form a loop obviously. Therefore, do we have a standing wave of opposite orientation than on the first wire (or hot call it whatever)? Or completely zero?

Comment: @bigboss, remember there is capacitance between the "primary" conductor and the reference conductor, so there is a loop. (Also, your argument applies equally to both conductors. If the open termination blocked all current in the transmission line there couldn't be current in either conductor)

Comment: @bigboss the standing wave *is* the loop. There's no path at DC, but RF is a different story.

Comment: @The Photon this was a pretty good explanation thanks!